# how can we separate totals on the basis of group

Tags: reporting-services

how can we separate the totals on the basis of column value. need to create a report which have multiple columns, every column have multiple values. need sum of every row group value. I have added sample as below. please help me regarding same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is as single as context clicking on your field and clicking "Add Total". Clicking this option will add a subtotal to your next group. Clicking again on that total will create a new total on the next group level until you eventually get to the final, grand total.